# When is the shortest path to some vertex found in Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: c++, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I've tried to understand [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and attempted to write my own implementation, and there are some things I don't understand:

1. When can I mark some vertex as visited and be sure that there is no shorter path to it?
2. When can I stop searching when looking for the shortest path between two vertices?

What's more, some sources say to use `decrease-key` instead of adding adjacent vertices to a priority queue. What does that mean and how does it work?

Comment: Normally I don't advise to use youtube for learning, but I've seen this video that takes you through the algorithm step by step. [computerphile on dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GazC3A4OQTE)

Comment: For Q1 you can be sure that there is no shorter path to it when it is visited and its path is the shortest of all currently accessed from a finalised node. At this point the node becomes "finalised" (which answers Q2).

Comment: Dijkstras algorithm visits nodes in increasing distance to the start node. When you visit a node, you can be sure to have found one of the shortest paths to it.

Comment: @fabian The order of visiting nodes depends on the details of the implementation and the order in which the edges are stored.

Comment: what helped me understanding the Dijkstra algorithms are these next points:
1. precondition, Dijkstra gives a solution if weights are positive. I think the real condition is no existence of negative cycle tough - but this adds noise. 
2. realize that any shortest path from A to B passing by C, gives you as well the best possible from A to C, from C to B. 
3. then the iteration idea of dijkstra: which you can start from state 0 (from starting node, the guarantee shortest path is giving by choosing the least weight to the next neighbor, this is a guarantee to be part of the solution

Comment: @ravenspoint The order of visiting nodes only depends on the implementation, if at the time of choosing the next node to visit there are multiple unvisited nodes at the same distance. Read steps `5.` and `6.` in [the description on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm) or the equivalent steps in any other description of the algorithm. If you're implementing a shortest path algorithm where this isn't the case, you're not implementing Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Djikstra's algorithm:

```
Initialise all distances to "infinity".

Push start onto a priority queue (front of queue will always holdest shortest distance from a finalised node)

Loop:
   Pop front of queue (effectively finalising it) - (desired end point is inaccessible if queue is empty here)
   If it is the desired end point, then done.
   Otherwise add to queue all nodes accessible from that finalised node whose distance could be improved.
```

Consider the following graph (@ravenspoint example with bottom line split)
[image]

Note that, to get from A to B by the shortest path:

B is only (explicitly) considered once.

E is never visited - you do NOT need the distance to all nodes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

using NodeType = char;

struct Edge
{
   NodeType dest;
   double wt;
};
bool operator < ( Edge a, Edge b ) { return a.dest < b.dest; }

using Graph  = map< NodeType, set<Edge> >;

//======================================================================

void read( istream &in, Graph &graph )
{
   graph.clear();
   NodeType a, b;
   double wt;
   while( in >> a >> b >> wt )
   {
      graph[a].insert( Edge{ b, wt } );
      graph[b].insert( Edge{ a, wt } );
   }
}

//======================================================================

double Dijkstra( Graph &graph, NodeType start, NodeType finish )
{
   const double LARGE = numeric_limits<double>::max();

   // Set all distances from start to infinity
   map<NodeType,double> dist;
   for ( auto n : graph ) dist[n.first] = LARGE;
   dist[start] = 0;

   // Create a priority queue that will be sorted by distance from source
   auto further = [&]( NodeType a, NodeType b ){ return dist[a] > dist[b]; };
   priority_queue< NodeType, vector<NodeType>, decltype(further) > Q( further );

   // Push all nodes accessible from the start onto the queue
   cout << "Finalised " << start << '\n';                  // Node with smallest currently-accessible distance
   for ( const Edge &edge : graph[start] )
   {
      dist[edge.dest] = edge.wt;
      Q.push( edge.dest );
      cout << "Queued " << edge.dest << '\n';
   }   

   // Dijkstra: take the smallest distance amongst those so far accessible and
   // finalise it (i.e. pop it from the front of the queue).
   while( !Q.empty() )
   {
      NodeType n = Q.top();
      cout << "Finalised " << n << '\n';                   // Smallest currently-accessible node
      if ( n == finish ) return dist[n];                   // If at the target then stop

      Q.pop();
      for ( const Edge &edge : graph[n] )
      {
         double test = dist[n] + edge.wt;
         if ( dist[edge.dest] > test )                     // If we improve a distance, then push onto queue
         {
            dist[edge.dest] = test;
            Q.push(edge.dest);
            cout << "Queued " << edge.dest << '\n';
         }
      }
   }

   // If we get this far then the target is inaccessible
   return -1.0;
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   istringstream in( "A C 1 \n"
                     "C B 2 \n"
                     "A D 10 \n"
                     "D E 10 \n"
                     "E B 80 \n" );
// ifstream in( "graph.in" );
// istream &in = cin;
   char start = 'A', finish = 'B';

   Graph G;
   read( in, G );
   double d = Dijkstra( G, start, finish );
   cout << "\nShortest path from " << start << " to " << finish << " is " << d << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Finalised A
Queued C
Queued D
Finalised C
Queued B
Finalised B

Shortest path from A to B is 3
```

Comment: U said that "E is never visited" (because B if found earlier and A-C-B has lesser weight than A-D, so also A-D-E and so on? Do I understand well?). But take a look at the same graph but with different weights: https://imgur.com/a/XtRvgg2. Now, 5 is lesser than 6 so we add vertex C to queue. Then we see that C is connected with B, so we end dijkstra with "shortest" path. But see that we cant end immediately. We see that A-D-E-B is shorter. So how it really works... :/ Im ultra confused

Comment: Obviously it depends on the weights, not just the connections. But for many real graphs if the weights are such that you can prove that the current shortest path can’t be beaten then you can finish early.

Comment: In your latest example, A is finalised and C and D are added to the queue. C is smaller, so at the front of the queue, so is finalised and B is added to the queue (but not at the front) with distance 9. D is at the front of the queue, so finalised and E is added to the queue. E is at the front, so is finalised and B is again added to the queue, but this time with smaller distance 8. Finally B is popped off the queue with distance 8. For this particular graph B is added twice to the queue and every node is considered.

Comment: The real problem is the term “visited”. Individual nodes may be “visited” more than once, some of those visits improving the distance. I prefer the term “finalised” - at this point the distance can never be improved. With the priority-queue method (insertion in sorted place) the distance to the front-of-the-queue node must increase or stay the same with every pop, so once the required end node is popped off that is it. I reiterate: for most graphs you will not need to visit or consider all nodes if there is only one end point.

Comment: I see, B is visited and added to queue. But when it will be processed depends on priority. The 9 (A-C-B) is greater than A-D, so we process E. 7 (A-D-E) is still lesser than (A-C-B), so it's processed first. Later we have 8 (A-D-E-B) which is lesser than 9 (A-C-B). So we process (A-D-E-B), so vertex in our queue is B with weight 8. So we can end searching shortest path if processed vertex from priority queue is equal to vertex being searched. Do I understand well?

Comment: Yes, @Szyszka947, you understand well. It has been a useful discussion.

Answer (score -1):

> When I can mark some vertex as visited and be sure that there is not shorter path to it

You cannot.  If a shorter path is found later, then the predecessor vertex and the distance will be updated.  The visited status remains true.

> When I can stop searching if I look for shortest path between A and B

When you have visited every vertex.  Note that you cannot stop earlier because, who knows, the last vertex you visit could have a edge to B which is part of the shortest path.

For example:

[image]

Depending on the order in which the edges are stored, the 1st time B is visited the path length is 100.  The second time, it is updated to 3.

---

You do not mention what coding language you use.  Here is a C++ implementation of Dijkstra https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/f07a29d10b5c14e6c085dd4eb6cb447e24c21eae/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L18-L76

Comment: So if I need to have shortest path from A to B then I still need to compute shortest paths for every vertex, yes? Could you mention something about `decrease-key` or it's too many for one question?

Comment: Yes. Dijsktra finds the shortest path from a specified node to every other node in the graph.

Comment: I do not know what decrease-key is.  I have never heard of it.  You probably should ask a new question about that and include a description of what it is and where you found it.

Comment: I see that implementation you mentioned uses `sptSet` to store visited vertices. So it wont process adjacent if it's marked as visited. So there is moment when we can say that some vertex won't have shorter path? What do I misunderstand?

Comment: The algo will not process a vertex if it is visited AND reprocessing it would not give a shorter distance.  If the distance is shorter than found in the previous visit it WILL be reprocessed.  Look at line 46.

Comment: Unless I misread much here, this answer is just plainly false: If you've found a path from Berlin to Paris that's 2000km long, there's no point in considering the route via New York... As soon as dijkstra chooses a node as the closest unvisited one and expands it, you can be sure there are no shorter routes, at least assuming there are no negative edge weights (With negative edge weights dijkstra doesn't work.): As soon as you visit a node, no nodes closer to the start node are visited and since no distances between 2 nodes are negative, the route via unvisited nodes is at least as long...

Comment: @fabian Please take a look at the example I have added to my answer.

Comment: You do NOT have to visit every node to run Dijkstra between two selected nodes: you simply have to guarantee that the desired end node is finalised. In the example, split the direct path A-B into A-D(10), D-E(10), E-B(80). Then Dijkstra's algorithm runs as follows: Finalise A (whence C and D accessible); C is smallest accessible, so finalise C (with B,D now accessible); B is smallest accessible from finalised nodes so finalise B. We have the shortest path from A to B WITHOUT VISITING E.

Comment: @ravenspoint In your example if a path from `A` to `C` is searched: you first visit `A` then you visit `C` and at that point you're done, since any shorter path can only use nodes closer to `A` but since the node to visit is chosen as the one with the current distance closest to `A`, there are no other nodes closer to `A` that could potentially result in a shorter path...